# Open pdf inapp Xamarin forms windows 8.1 winrt app

Tags: pdf, xamarin.forms, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, render

I'm implementing a xamarin forms windows 8.1(WinRT) app.
I want to render pdf in app.
I have tried custom renderer and mozzila pdf.js which is not working for me.
Please suggest me how to do it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing pdf.js will give you a pdf viewer and the pdf will render just fine. Just make sure you retrieve the pdf file in the same folder(Assets) where you stored it.

Alternatively, you can convert the pdf into a bitmap image and set the source to an Image control. That will work fine as well. 
Refer https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/133501/is-it-possible-to-print-a-pdf-with-pdf-viewer - This link contains a sample to print the pdf by converting into a bitmap image. You can modify the code for displaying.

Comment: I'm not able to render pdf using pdf.js.
i'm building windows 8.1 app using xamarin forms which not able to render pdf.

Comment: I had done it in Xamarin.forms UWP , not sure about WP8.1.. Is it showing any error? and i assume you were referring to https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/  for implementing pdf.js.